# Convert a vector of 3 uint8 to a uint32 in simulink

Tags: matlab, byte, simulink, 32-bit, uint8t

I had a vector of 3 elements all type uint8 that need to be converted to a uint32, I’m struggling to find the correct block to do that I tried unpacking the signals but then that creates a problem with the input width size as it just outputs 3 signals. Does anyone have any idea if there’s such a block in simulink

Edit: A data packager block takes in a uint32 as an input and then outputs a vector of 3 uint8 elements. I’m trying to convert that back to one uint32 outputs but I’m unable to do so using the byte unpack as the size of the vector is incompatible.

I gave data unpack, signal selector and data conversion all a go, and they all outputted the wrong size of signal. As they outputted 3 signals instead of 1 uint32 signal

Comment: This is very unclear: I don’t know what you have nor what you want to get out of it nor what you tried. You start off saying you have a vector of 3 elements, but then you talk about signals, and I don’t see how that relates. If you show some code for how to create mock input data, and what your expected result should be, then I think it’ll be much more clear.

Comment: One interpretation of your post is that you have three bytes that need to be converted into a single 3-byte value.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I’ve added some comments. Thank you

Comment: most probably i would go for a matlab function block and use the typecast() function. Be careful with the machine endians in that case. If your machine is little endian there may be needed a swapbytes too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to unpack uint32 data into double and then separates the result into three numbers based on their values. Take for example, a 6 digit number such as 123456. 12, 34 and 56 can be converted to uint8 in order to send as a three byte package. In the receiver on the other hand, they need to combine to form the original number. Sending part is as follows. Receiver is opposite.
[image: sending 123456 as three uint8]